# Working on a region given by union of parametric curves

Tags: calculus, integration, area, parametric

As the title says I need to calculate the area of the region enclosed by a certain curve which is the union of 4 curves in that form :

$\alpha$ : [-1,1] $\to$  $\mathcal R^2$ , $\alpha_1$($t$) = $t^2$ , $\alpha_2(t)$ = $2-t^2$

Now this is not exactly one of the curves of the exercise but an example. 
I need to understand if I can just sum up all of the areas by using this :

A = $\int ydx$ where in the example it should be $\int_{-1}^1 ((2-t^2)*2t)dt$

Moreover making a purely graphical reasoning I can confirm the result found analytically.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Union of four curves, or of the two curves you've listed?

Comment: @KajHansen Area of the region enclosed by curve s = a U b U c U d , where a, b, c and d curves are written like the example I did.

Comment: Why multiply the functions instead of subtracting?

Comment: It does not sound like what is wanted is $\int_{-1}^1y\,dx$, rather it sounds more like an exercise in graphing the Cartesian graphs of parametric curves which bound some region in the Cartesian coordinate system followed by finding the area of the region bounded by the curves.